# Swift 2.0 / iOS Unwrapping Error

Tags: xcode, swift

I am new to Swift and am trying to make a basic application that displays a string based on entered text.

I understand that with iOS 9 and Swift 2.0, there are several new changes. I am watching a tutorial from iOS 8 and Swift 1.2 and noticed that the code I am trying to run is not compiling, stating that I need an "!" to unwrap a variable. What is the best way to learn about unwrapping and when it is necessary? A tutorial or video would be extremely helpful:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet var resultLabel: UILabel!

@IBOutlet var age: UITextField!

@IBOutlet var convertedAge: UILabel!

@IBAction func checkAge(sender: AnyObject) {

    var enteredAge = Int(age.text)

    //exclamation mark "unwraps" a variable
    //a way for the programmer to ensure that a value will be an int
    var catYears = enteredAge! * 7

    resultLabel.text = "Your cat is \(catYears)"

    print(age.text)

}
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
 }


}
```

[image]

Comment: It's all in Apple's very readable book. Start from there and you'll have most of the basic stuff covered.

Comment: The Swift Programming Language (Swift 2.2) by Apple Inc. https://itun.es/jp/jEUH0.l

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/OptionalChaining.html

I am suggesting apple's own source for this purpose. If you can pay for the course, also Lynda.com has a nice Swift essentials course